# How do I denote (shade/hatch) a curved surface in a technical drawing?

Tags: technical-drawing

I am creating some 2d technical drawings, is there a standard way to shade/hatch a curved surface?[image]

Comment: I'm no expert in tech drawing, but I found this PDF on drawing section views: http://user.engineering.uiowa.edu/~mie032/Support/EG/EG07_Section_Views.pdf - which seems to suggest only the flat surface of the cut section is typically shaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Billy Kerr 's linked document correctly shows, in a section view, the area hatched is ***only*** the portion of the object *directly sliced by* the section plane.

In some section drawings, one may choose to *also use shading* to indicate form, if the view ends up confusing and the object forms are complex; in those cases, great care must be taken to clearly differentiate the cut poché from the surface shading to avoid any confusion - this is why in *most* simple technical drawing sections, the illustrator chooses to eschew surface shading completely - for simplicity and clarity.

In architectural sections, sometimes we keep the surface shading to help clear form reading - I did that in this perspective section of a sub-assembly of a complex interior door - though for this example the sectioned area doesn't have a  hatch, it has a poché, which indicates it having been sectioned, but not any specific materiality:

[image]

But more typically in architectural sections we *only* hatch *cut areas*, and avoid surface shading, and if a section is not schematic, we show the hatch for the relevant sectioned material, just as is common in other technical drawing typologies:

[image]

Here's a super-quick example (at client's site w/ none of my typical CAD tools - this was Affinity Designer running fast and loose) to show conceptual relationships:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's great. I was curious, because I don't remember learning anything about it, but have seen technical drawings with various different gradient hatching denoting curves. I like the concept of the last image above. I may incorporate that into my work.